# LayoutInflater.java with internal errros

Tags: java, android-studio, layout-inflater, internal-class

Inside my "native" LayoutInflater.java there are several imports that aren't working, causing several errors warnings. I've noticed it after Android Studio asked to update something but I can't remember what was it. By the way, even after formating the computer and re-installing Android Studio the problem persists.

The imports that failed are:

```
import android.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.annotation.NonNull;
import android.annotation.Nullable;
import android.annotation.SystemService;
import android.annotation.TestApi;
import android.compat.annotation.UnsupportedAppUsage;
import com.android.internal.R;
```

So, everything inside the class related to those imports is red, and there many of them.

My Android Studio version is:
Android Studio 4.1.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283, built on November 4, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1237M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

Is it normal? Can it affect somehow my app?

Thanks for your attention and help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to file > Invalidate cache or Restart.
Then click invalidate and restart and it should restart.
If some processes are going on, let them complete. This usually happens in the beginning so it is pretty normal.

Comment: Hi Simran, I've tried this but it didn't work. The app is running without problems, but those warnings are really annoying.

Comment: Did you try the clean option in the build tab. Sometimes even that works.

Comment: Just tried cleaning, but didn't work either.
But, as the app is running, I'll leave it this way.
Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: If something works then update me with the solution as well. That would help me in future.